# How do I subtract using SQL in MYSQL between two date time values and retrieve the result in minutes or second?

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I want to subtract between two date time values using SQL in MySQL such that I get the interval in minutes or seconds. Any ideas? I want to run a SQL query that retrieves uses from a database who have logged in like 10 minutes from the time.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

There are functions `TIMEDIFF(expr1,expr2)`, which returns the value of `expr1-expr2`, and `TIME_TO_SEC(expr3)`, which expresses `expr3` in seconds.

Note that `expr1` and `expr2` are datetime values, and `expr3` is a time value only.

Check [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) for more info.

Answer (score 78):

[TIMESTAMPDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) is like TIMEDIFF which Matthew states, except it returns the difference of the two datetimes in whatever units you desire (seconds, minutes, hours, etc).

For example,

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,LogOutTime,LogInTime) AS TimeLoggedIn
FROM LogTable
```

Would return the number of minutes the user was logged in (assuming you stored this kind of thing in a table like that).

Comment: Note that TIMEDIFF(expr1,expr2) results in expr1 - expr2, where TIMESTAMPDIFF(unit,expr1,expr2) results in expr2 - expr1.  Just something to watch out for.

Answer (score 14):

I would do it like this - fetch where last activity is within 10 mins of now

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE last_activity >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)
```

Comment: It is a bad idea to use some operations on the index field. In this case MySQL ignores that index: [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9619f0/1) (check how many fields are processed when you are use DATE_ADD on the field and how many fields are processed when you are use DATE_SUB on the constant (like NOW()).

So your query MUST BE next:

    `SELECT * FROM table WHERE last_activity >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)`

This rule is also applied for the other fields that are the part of the index.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,LogOutTime,LogInTime) AS TimeLoggedIn
FROM LogTable
```

This example shall ruin the time if its used by using millitary time. So for calculating millitairy time I do not recommend it Because it outputs negative values.

Answer (score -1):

You can try and cast them to Unix Time stamp, and take the difference.