# How to get difference in minutes betwen two timestamps

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, timestamp

I want to ask how to find the time difference of two fields in minutes. eg in 'in' field  filled 2014-07-12 19:00:00 , and in 'out' field filled 2014-07-12 20:30:00 , the time difference will be automatically saved in the 'duration' field

```
----in--------------|-------out-----------| duration
2014-07-12 19:00:00 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 0
--------------------------------------------------
```

when i click update button it will updated like,

```
-------in-----------|---------out---------| duration

2014-07-12 19:00:00 | 2014-07-12 20:30:00 | 90
--------------------------------------------------
```

thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I subtract using SQL in MYSQL between two date time values and retrieve the result in minutes or second?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981262/how-do-i-subtract-using-sql-in-mysql-between-two-date-time-values-and-retrieve-t)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `TIMESTAMPDIFF` function, as below:

```
SELECT 
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, in, out) duration
FROM mytable;
```

**Reference**:

[TIMESTAMPDIFF function on MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff)

Answer (score 0):

Manual for [**TIME_TO_SEC**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec) function.

```
SELECT (TIME_TO_SEC(`in`)-TIME_TO_SEC(`out`))/60 AS duration FROM TABLE_NAME ;
```